# How to deal with empty/null values that appear as an Error on my transform tables?

Tags: palantir-foundry

I have applied a numeric formula transform on my transform table that has inherited null/empty values from upstream charts. How can I resolve this error?
[image: Show error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinterpreting the null as 0 will get rid of the error, because the numeric formula transform is expecting a numeric value. In order to do this, you must use the coalesce transform in the transform table by first selecting the column that contains the null values, and then replacing it with 0 as shown it the screenshot below.
[image: coalesce process]